# how turn off styles.css from default/default/css in magento

Tags: magento

Could you please tell me if it's possible to turn off loading of styles.css from
default/default/css when I use theme default/my_theme and that doesn't have styles.css?
Why does magento load for other theme styles.css from default/default?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `local.xml` in your theme, in your `<default>` handler use
under `reference head`
`removeItem` to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

### Define `layout.xml`

This layout xml file is a unique layout file, that will be processed at last by Magento. This makes this layout file extremely good to remove/change layout appearance. Here you need to remove a css file. So you can use this.

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/styles.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

### Description

`head` is a special block that is used to hold css and js files. `styles.css` resides in this block. It is included through `page.xml` layout file.

```
 <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
```

This is how it is included to head section. Here the action takes place `addCss`. This method uses a type `skin_css` by default. ie any **css** file that resides in skin directory can included by this method. You can also use `addItem` method. But you need to specify `type` attribute as `skin_css`, in order to use that method.

In order to remove an item that is added by `addCss` or `addItem` method, you can use `removeItem`. This method accepts two parameters. `type` and `name`. In our case `type` is `skin_css` (since `styles.css` resides in `skin`) and name is `css/styles.css`.

Hope that helps